# Additional GitHub Project Page

Tags: github, github-pages, github-projects

I have a primary github.io page but I would like to create other pages. I've read you can only have one main github.io page but that you can have multiple project pages. How does this work? Does anyone have a GitHub repo that shows the architecture of how to achieve this? Thanks!